# input type date taking as 11-Dec-2018 in chrome browser

Tags: php, html

```
<input type="Date" class="form-control" value="2018-12-11" />
```

It showing 11-Dec-2018 in chrome browser. But in firefox, it's working fine.

Comment: my self both browser showing "12/11/2018" . Please let me know what you are expecting format???

Comment: `11-Dec-2018` is correct.

Comment: i am using laravel 5.6 with html .For date picker I used above code but i am getting the result in this format in chrome.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to change input type="date" format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format)

Comment: ^ Make sure to read the comments below the accepted answer as well.

Comment: here is the post about same issue [https://stackoverflow.com/a/31162426/8343184](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31162426/8343184)

Comment: 11-12-2018 is my expecting date format

Comment: @irshad2809 - That's the same question as the suggested duplicate. Btw, how did you manage to comment with only 1 in rep? :-o

Comment: @rajukumar - Did you read the suggested duplicate? Make sure to glance through all the answers and comments.

Comment: Yes i change it code but not working..